# excel Vba copy paste to another workbook

Tags: copy, paste

I need to copy a value on an activesheet cell A1, to another workbook located at d:\location\aaa.xls cell C3.

I just need it to paste special the values, if possible I do not want to have to open the workbook aaa.xls - i just need the values injected or at least open close.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You have top open the aaa.xls in your current context to update any values in that file.